# Tabulatorjs - Virtualized the columns

Tags: tabulator

I'm coming from react-virtualized and I surprised that only rows are virtualized in Tabulatorjs. (last version : 4.1.3)
For my need, I'd like to display data from time-series, where each column is a date/hour. ( at least 2000 colums.)

I created a jsfiddle with only 50 columns and I can see all of it in the dom. Is there any way to virtualize the rows and the columns ?

-> https://jsfiddle.net/Lu1nfkwr/3/

```
// really simple options
let options = {
  columns: columns,
  data: tabledata,
}
```

thx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment this isn't possible. Tabulators virtual DOM is currently row based.

Column based virtualization is currently under development and is scheduled for one of the next few releases

Comment: Ok, Thx for the reply.
I took a look in roadmap but I don't see this feature 
https://trello.com/b/rPZ0Yavc/tabulator-roadmap

Comment: Thats because it is more of an incremental ongoing improvement rather than a specific feature for release. over the next few releases the entire virtual DOM system is getting incremental improvements. it is covered off in this issue: https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/1437